# Free dyno hours remaining but heroku app showing info code H82 in logs

Tags: php, heroku

I have been using heroku for sometime now, I made a website on it. It was working until yesterday but today it showed some error so I checked my heroku logs it displayed:

> 2016-10-27T08:15:57.558031+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H82
>   desc="Free app running time quota exhausted" method=GET
>   path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   request_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   fwd="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I am a little lost at this because when I checked heroku ps it showed:

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 496h 25m (90%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping
```

Kindly suggest how to solve this query.

Answer (score 0):

I've seem some people complaining of these dynos that go out before the time. I believe that the best thing to do in your case is contacting Heroku support.

You can try some workarounds, as [adding a credit card](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool) to your account in order to gain more hours, and after that if it's still not working, change the dyno type and then back to free to see if it reloads.

But only Heroku support will be able to really check what is happening.

Comment: How do you contact them if it says `Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community.`?